# What's wrong with my Java JSON Parser?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm very new to parsing JSON, and I'm using the parser from here https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/. I'm trying to parse data from the NYTimes, specifically the "web_urls" and "main" in "docs" , and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" JSON.JSONException: JSONObject["docs"] not found.
at JSON.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:475)
at JSON.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:557)
at News.sendGet(News.java:53)
at News.main(News.java:80)

Exception in thread "main" JSON.JSONException: JSONObject["main"] not found.
at JSON.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:475)
at JSON.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:656)
at News.sendGet(News.java:56)
at News.main(News.java:78)
```

Here is the url to the JSON: http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=water&begin_date=20141101&end_date=20141101&api-key=sample-key

Below is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import JSON.JSONObject;


public class News 
{
/* Instance Field */
private final static String apiNYT = "###"; // api key for NYTimes

/**
 * This is an HTTP Get Request to retrieve articles from 
 * @throws Exception
 * @param url request
 */
private void sendGet(String url) throws Exception 
{
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // Read the JSON
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    // Response is the JSON form of type StringBuffer 
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // jstr is the string version of the JSON form
    String jstr = response.toString();


    //print result
    System.out.println(jstr);

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jstr);

    // arr is a JSONArray that records the docs array
    JSON.JSONArray arr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("docs");
    String blurb = "";
    String title = "";

    // Loop through the docs array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    {
         blurb += arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("web_url");
         title += arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("headline").getString("main");
    }

    System.out.println(blurb);
    System.out.println(title);
}

/**
 * Main method
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{

    News http = new News();

    // Test call for NYTimes API (articles with the word "water" in title on 14/11/01)
    String url = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=water&begin_date=20141101&end_date=20141101&api-key="
            + apiNYT ;

    http.sendGet(url);  
}
}
```

Comment: "docs" is inside "response".  Learn how to read JSON.  (It may help to format with a formatter such as http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
JSON.JSONArray arr = jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("docs");
```

The `docs` array is nested in the `response` object, so need to process that level first. You would probably want to split this up into multiple lines and add some null checks.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. However, I'm now trying to figure out how to get the `main` nested in `headline` nested in `docs` nested in `response`. Why do I get an error of `JSONObject ["main"] not found"` when I include the following in my for loop? `title += arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("headline").getString("main");`

Comment: @tbee - Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Comment: Not all `docs` entries have the `main` string in the `headline` object. E.g., the fifth one, about the "Green bean casserole" does not have it. Use `optString()` instead of `getString()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void sendGet(String url) throws Exception 
{
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // Read the JSON
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    // Response is the JSON form of type StringBuffer 
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // jstr is the string version of the JSON form
    String jstr = response.toString();


    //print result
    System.out.println(jstr);

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jstr);

    // arr is a JSONArray that records the docs array
    **JSON.JSONArray arr = jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("docs")**
    String blurb = "";

    // Loop through the docs array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    {
         blurb += arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("web_url");
    }

    System.out.println(blurb);

}
```